# Upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04.1: why do I need to wait several days?

Tags: ubuntu, dist-upgrade

> upgrades from 16.04 LTS will not be enabled until a few days after the 18.04.1 release

1. Why do they wait "few days" after the 18.04.1 release?  The version 18.04.1 is already here, but sudo apt-get dist-upgrade refuses to upgrade.
2. How to force the upgrade now? Are there any bad things if I do it?

Comment: It's better to stop using ubuntu now.

Comment: @IporSircer why?

Comment: You need to ask this question to the Ubuntu devs, nobody else can give you an answer.

Comment: When the tool for upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS is ready (tested and debugged), you will be offered to use it. You can try manually before that, but that will be more risky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this command at your own risk:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

for the development release:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

more info: 
[man-page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/do-release-upgrade.8.html),
[documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/installing-upgrading.html.en)

Comment: sudo do-release-upgrade => No new release found.